# PowerShell script to deploy model metadata from *bim files to SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: powershell, powerbi, gitlab, ssas, tabular-editor

I have a remote server that will be used as Power BI and Analytics Services on premises
Everything necessary is installed there (SQL + SSAS +PBIRS + Kerberos)
One of my challenges is to deploy model metadata from *.bim files (that are stored in GitLab) to SSAS with the help of PowerShell

I would like to write a PowerShell script that would be executed from GitLab CI pipeline (note that I can only build Linux based containers that can run PowerShell scripts) which would grab specific .bim file and deployed it to SSAS (TabularEditor might be used?!)
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What format are the files?  See : https://www.wbdg.org/bim/cobie/common-bim-files?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am talking about .bim file format that is used by the Microsoft Power BI Desktop application. It is a file format that is used to store data models and associated metadata in a Power BI report.

Comment: I'm an expert on importing data and no very little of your format.  From my link above there seems to be lots of different type of BIM files.  Yours is probably one of them.  None of the files on the link have bim extension.  I recommend you open your BIM and look at the ascii header to see if there is a description of the file.  All the files types at my link are referred to a BIM.  You desktop application is a project and may contain more than one file type.